# BigQuery SQL Cast error: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signature: ANY = ANY

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery, casting, int64

I'm getting this error while running a query in BigQuery in the part of 4th line (highlighted in italics).
In this query, table 1 has a data field 'Lsc' as String data type and table 2 has a data field 'Sc' as Integer data type.

Query-

SELECT safe_cast(a.Lsc as INT64), b.Sc
FROM table1 as a
LEFT JOIN table2 as b
on *a.Lsc* = b.Sc

What am I doing wrong ?

I tried with Cast as well but same error.
I also tried as below but error remains-

SELECT safe_cast(a.Lsc as INT64) as a.Sc, b.Sc
FROM table1 as a
LEFT JOIN table2 as b
on *a.Lsc* = b.Sc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
SELECT safe_cast(a.Lsc as INT64) as Lsc, b.Sc
FROM table1 as a
LEFT JOIN table2 as b ON safe_cast(a.Lsc as INT64) = b.Sc
```

In your example in the JOIN you were comparing an integer with a string, that could be the reason for the error